# Why `preg_match` returns a integer?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Why the `preg_match` function returns a integer, instead of a boolean? [The documentation](http://php.net/preg_match) mentions `false` as indicative of failure, but why not `null`?

Comment: Do you have some code?

Comment: Because that's what they decided to return. It makes no difference really, since usually you're only interested in "there's a match", which is 1, which is truthy.

Comment: My guess: Because `preg_match_all` *"returns the number of full pattern matches (which might be zero), or FALSE if an error occurred."* `preg_match` is simply the single-match version of `preg_match_all`, but they didn't bother changing the return type.

Comment: The answer frequently given to these questions: "because php".

Comment: Of course this is something agreed in the PHP community. But many conventions are not random ("because php").

Comment: `null` isn't really indicative of a failure, more like a gaellic shrug, a puff on a Gauloise and "I 'ave noh ideeaaa"... at least `false` is definitively not true.

Comment: I think the return value must express a test result... Is it wrong? `true` represents a positive result, `false` represents negative result and `null` as not-a-result.

Comment: `null` represents the absence of a value, it means neither *success* nor *failure*. It's *mu*. In this case, `1` means "found one", `0` means "found none" and `false` means "error".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess, this is in concordance with `preg_match_all` - both functions return how many times a regex has matched. As to the `false` vs. `null` issue, it doesn't actually matter. `preg_` functions emit a warning if something bad happens (e.g. a malformed regular expression). If you handle errors in a sensible way, you'll never need to check for this value. Example:

```
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
}
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");

$regex = '/x+++++/'; # hmm...

try {
    $number = preg_match($regex, "input");
    print "matched $number times";
} catch(ErrorException $e) {
    print "ERROR " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: "Return `false` on error" policy exist since the absense of exceptions in PHP. In that era, I think that concordance with `preg_match_all` is reasonable.